# How to do where on with model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this condition where I need to filter the project list according to the login user if the user is inside the members() model.

```
public function index(Request $request = null, $search = null)
{
    $user = $this->user;
    $data = project_registry::with('members', 'members.profile')->where('isdelete', 0);

    if(!$user->project_view) {
        // here i need to do the filter for the login user to view project where they are the member of the project
    }

    if(!is_null($request['search'])) {
        $search = $request['search'];
        $data->where(function($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('Project_Code', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->orWhere('Project_Short_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
        });
    }

    $data = $data->orderBy('Project_ID')->paginate(20);

    return view('project.index', compact('data', 'search'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use wherehas

```
project_registry::whereHas('members', function($q) use ($user) {
    $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
})->...
```

Comment: Wow.. It is helpful. Thank you ;)

Comment: Right in the official [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Ya.. I overlooked it. Btw tq